# How can I get text to be vertically-aligned to the bottom and fill the empty space above it as needed?

Tags: html, css

My designer came up with the following design thing:

[image]

However I'm not entirely sure how to get the text to stick at the bottom like you can see in the middle. I thought I could do something like (inline css is for example only):

```
<div style="vertical-align: bottom; height:30px;">
  <h2 style="line-height: 15px;font-size: 15px;padding: 0; margin:0;">
    Foo bar foo
  </h2>
</div>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use two divs for each 'button', if you set the outer divs (the black bits) to be position: absolute or position: relative you can use bottom:0 on the inner div containing the text. 
This'll have the effect of aligning the text div at the bottom of it's parent. 
Note: You can't use the vertical-align property, as that only does what you expect if you're looking at a table-cell.

Comment: That's exactly what I would do as well. Just make sure you know how many lines you will have (2 here) because else it will be cut off on top (guessing you will also use `overflow: hidden`).